# Prove matrix rank is 0 or 1

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a_{ij}=r_ {i}.s _{j}$, prove that rank of matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ is  either 0 or 1.

It's obvious that if $r = \begin{bmatrix}r_1& r_2 & \cdots& r_n\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $s = \begin{bmatrix}s_1& s_2 & \cdots& s_n\\ \end{bmatrix}^T$ the answer is a scalar which if it'd be zero the matrix rank is zero otherwise it's 1.

But if $r = \begin{bmatrix}r_1& r_2 & \cdots& r_n\\ \end{bmatrix}^T$ and $s = \begin{bmatrix}s_1& s_2 & \cdots& s_n\\ \end{bmatrix}$ the answer is a $n*n$ matrix:

$A_{n*n} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  r_1s_1 & r_1s_2 & \cdots & r_1s_n \\
  r_2s_1 & r_2s_2 & \cdots & r_2s_n \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  r_ns_1 & r_ns_2 & \cdots &r_ns_n 
 \end{bmatrix}$

How can I prove that above matrix rank is zero or one?

Comment: Hint: Row reduce.

Comment: How exactly it is  ?? Could you help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min( \operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)) \leq 1$, so the conclusion follows.

Comment: Actually $\max(\operatorname{rank} A, \operatorname{rank} B)\le 1$ as both vectors might be the zero vector. Anyway, shouldn't that be $\min$ rather than $\max$?

Comment: @celtschk For the first one, you are absolutely right, for the second one you are technically correct, but it doesn't matter in this case haha. Anyway, I will correct this!

Answer (score 1):

If all $r_k=0$ we get the zero-matrix. Otherwise let $r_1\neq0$.  In this case the $k^{\text{th}}$ row (for $k=2,\dotsc,n$) is the first row multiplied by $r_k/r_1$.

Completely different approach: determine the kernel of $A$. From
$\vec 0=(r^Ts)x^T=r^T(sx^T)$ we conclude $sx^T=0_{\mathbb R}$. Hence either $s=\vec0$ or $r=0$ -- in this case the kernel is $n$-dimensional -- or else the kernel is the $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane of all vectors perpendicular to $s$.